# NSData from a custom object

Tags: cocoa, serialization, deserialization, nsdata

I'm working on client/server application which uses AsyncSocket. For transferring data, it uses `NSData`.

How can I insert my custom object, containing `NSNumber`s, `NSInteger`s, and `NSString`s into an `NSData` object and then get it back out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to insert (serialize) a custom object into an NSData object is to use NSCoding and NSKeyedArchiver.

First, have your custom object implement the NSCoding protocol.
Example here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-97234

Then, for information on using your object with NSKeyedArchiver refer to:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/creating.html

Hope that helps!